# Uninstalling Windows XP

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a Dell built in 2003 running Windows XP Home. I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 onto a partition on my hard drive. Now I am not able to boot with XP, only Ubuntu. (on boot up screen, when I choose to boot with XP, it continuously loops back to boot up menu)I would like to backup all my files within XP and totally delete XP OS leaving the complete hard drive for Ubuntu. How do I go about doing this? Where do i begin?

Comment: You can use Boot repair to get back into Windows. After that all you will have to do is back your things up. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

You can mount the XP partition within Ubuntu, using a bit of command line magic, and back up your Windows files to a USB disk, without booting into XP if you like.

Bring up a terminal, and run the following command to start with:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

It should display a list of partitions available on your system. One of these is likely to be your Windows XP partition. It might look a little like this:

```
/dev/sda1               1        1959    15735636    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

See that /dev/sda1? That's the think we're interested in. It could be hda1 or sda2 or sda5 - but it should have W95 at the end there somewhere (or potentially NTFS as Danatela points out below - depending on what installation options you chose for Windows).

Next we need to mount it. Run the following:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir Windows
sudo mount /dev/sda1 Windows
```

(Where /dev/sda1 is the W95 partition mentioned above). Although there are plenty of other arguments you could supply to the 'mount' command, ubuntu is smart enough to work out what you're after in this instance.

Ok, you now have your Windows files available in /tmp/Windows. Bring up your file manager, point it there, slot in a USB disk, and copy off the files you need. You won't be able to delete the files with your normal user account, since we mounted the drive as 'root' (via sudo), but the permissions should be adequate to give you read-only access to the files.

Once you're done, you can reboot your computer, and reinstall Ubuntu completely.

Comment: Windows XP installs itself on NTFS by default

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way to do this without re-installing Ubuntu completely, its a bit more complicated, but Ubuntu does not need to be set up again.

Firs of all, copy all the data you want from your windows partition (using the method described in RedPhoenix's answer, or you can simply open the file browser, select the windows disk, and copy the data off of it.)

Here is what you do to delete the windows partition and add it to the ubuntu partition. This method is more complicated, but you can hopefully will be able to keep your files. You will still need to do a backup, but if everything goes well, you should be able to keep your files.
To use this method, boot up on you Ubuntu install, CD/USB stick, click try ubuntu on this computer, open the dash, and open the program called gparted.

click on your XP partition (it is the one formatted as NTSF) In this image, it is the first partition [image: Step 1]Then click the red delete (on the top left hand corner) button. There should now be a big gray are where windows xp used to be. Next, click on the partition and click the resize button (in the partition menu), then drag the slider on the left to encompass the big gray area. Click ok. It should now look somewhat like this:
[image: Step 2]

Finally you must click on the ext4 partition, and resize it to include unallocated space (like in the this screenshot)
[image: Step 3]
Finally, click the green check button to start the process. This will take a long time, especially if you have a large hard drive. Now you are mostly there, you just need to re-configure grub (the program that manages booting up). To do this, follow the instructions [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/)!

IMPORTANT: while gparted is working, do not click anything or mess around with the program, it might crash and corrupt your data (i learned this the hard way)!

**EDIT:** [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToRemoveWindows) is a more in depth tutorial if you need more information.

Comment: In reference to your first image, after selecting the windows partition, I am unable to delete it as all actions are greyed out.
@DeveloperNewb

Comment: First you must right click it and select unmount. Then you can modify it. (Note: you need to be running off of a live CD to modify the ubuntu partitions.)